# Calculate string similarity / Levenshtein distance without transposed value's column

Tags: excel, similarity

I have often to get done two kinds of tasks:

1. after scraping a website I have an URL list (in one column), where I want find all URLs, which are similar one to another. The similarities are different and can be on the URL's middle or end, like ID's, parameters etc. - so it isn't enough to sort URLs alphabetically. URL examples:

   - http://example.com/page-1
   - http://example.com/page-2.html
   - http://example.com/page/12.php
   - http://example.com/1/page/2
   - http://example.com/page/1/2.htm
2. I have keywords list, which I want to cluster on their similarity. In this case too is it not enough to sort them alphabetically, because the order of keywords can differ. Keyword examples:

   - buy iphone
   - buy iphone in berlin
   - buy iphone cover
   - buy i-phone covr
   - iphone cover berlin

The question is: how can I calculate the similarity of values in a column in cases I describe?

I need results like a table with 101 column: in the first column are my values, whose similarity should be calculated, The come 100 columns: 100% similarity, 99% similarity end so on: in these columns should be valued filled in, which are similar to the certain value from the first column:

```
Values  100%     99%              ...     5%
value1  value2   value3,value7            value5
value2
value3
value4
value5
value6
value7
```

I setup a dashboard to calculate the Levenshtein distance, but this dashboard is build like: first column contains values, then this column is transposed, and the Levenshtein distance is calculated for each values pair.
It looks like:

```
Values     value1   value2   value3
value1     100%      75%      95%
value2     75%       100%     30%
value3     95%       30%      100%
```

But i have too many values, so i can't build transposed tables - they will be too big.

The more precise question is: how g i get this calculation done without to build transposed tables , so each values pair has own cell?

Comment: Try installing fuzzy lookup plug in in Excel. It actually compares two strings and gives a similarity index between the two strings as output. This should definitely solve your problem

Comment: Agree with @KanikeVamshiKrishna - without a plugin, what you're asking for is (1) the algorithm to determine what 'closeness' means, and then (2) code to calculate it.

Comment: @KanikeVamshiKrishna: tested it, but got no satisfying results. Fuzzy Lookup compares two columns with values to each other. Bu i should compare all values in the same column to each other.

Comment: So its more like an inter-row operation. Comparing different values in same column with each other ?

Comment: @KanikeVamshiKrishna Correct! Could you point me into the right direction?

Comment: Then breaking the URL's in the column into multiple tokens based on a special character in the URL and then going that way would help. As you say its URL data I feel its possible